# Use compareTo method from another class

Tags: java

I have a class called `classes` who has this compareto method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object other) {
    Cours ot = (Cours)other;
    String heure2 = ot.heure;
    int autre = Integer.parseInt(heure2.substring(0,2));
    int le = Integer.parseInt(this.heure.substring(0,2));

    if (autre > le) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (autre == le) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }

}
```

I have another class called `day` that has a list of `classes` :

```
private List<Cours> journee;
```

And a method to sort the classes:

```
public void TrieListe() {
    Collections.sort(journee);
}
```

When I use `TrieListe()` everything works fine, I can sort the list.

But I've added another class called `Weeks` which contains a List of `Days`
And now I want to use TrieList() from that class :

```
private List<Days> leWeek;

public void TrieListe() {
    Collections.sort(leWeek);
}
```

So how can I use my `compareTo` method from my `classes` class using sort() in my `Weeks` class.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to use the same compareTo method? Your "Weeks" class has a member called "heure"?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator- maybe

Comment: I want to compare each day using the "heure" properties in classes So there are sorted by " heure "

Comment: No my weeks class doesnt have a member called "heure"

Comment: @yoyani I've lost track of your classes. I've post a possible solution of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `abstract` class `AComparableByHour` and make your classes extend it.

```
public abstract class AComparableByHour implements Comparable<AComparableByHour> {

public abstract String getHeure();

// Your comparison method goes here 
@Override
public int compareTo(AComparableByHour ot) {
    String heure2 = ot.getHeure();

    int autre = Integer.parseInt(heure2.substring(0,2));
    int le    = Integer.parseInt(this.getHeure().substring(0,2));

    if( autre > le){
        return 1;
    }

    if( autre == le){
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

}

```
public class Cours extends AComparableByHour {
    // This method is mandatory now. 
    // You could move it to the new superclass
    public String getHeure() {   
          return heure;
    }
    ...
}

public class Days extends AComparableByHour {
    public String getHeure() {
         return heure;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have a class called `classes` who has this compareto method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object other) {
```

This is already wrong. Your class should implement `Comparable<classes>` (noting that `classes` is a truly terrible name for a class, for at least three separate reasons), which will force the method signature to be:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(classes other) {
```

Comment: How does this answer the question on invoking the same comparison method from different classes?